# Get an arraylist from Parse.com in a new Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I wish to get an array from the Parse cloud.  After tapping on an item in a list (which contains the ParseObject reference), the item will open a new activity and from this I want to get the array list stored in the latLngPoints key in Parse.  I have googled and only found the following solution but it does not work:

```
  ArrayList<ParseGeoPoint> parseList = (ArrayList<ParseGeoPoint>) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("latLngPoints");
```

Is it possible to even do it this way, or will I have to create a Parse object and create a request to get the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

ParseObjects are not parcelable. You can pass an array list of longs that represent lat and long